# Confused about using reduce and what it's actually trying to do

Tags: ruby

I have done Rails development a bit but haven't for a while.

I have never used reduce / inject other than to sum up values (which seems to be the main example I've seen online) but would like to understand better what it does (and to be honest, just its syntax). I have heard it referred to as the `functional` part of Ruby but based upon examples, not sure what that means.

Looking at the example in the docs (the longest word example) https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce seems to imply that it is useful for selecting a value out of a series at end but this doesn't seem very `functional`.

My understanding is that it accumulates to the initial value passed into reduce. But in this code fragment, I'm not sure why it's not accumulating (I'm expecting "some joe birds joe bees" or some variation).

```
# expect 'some joe birds joe bees'

def say_joe(name)
  puts "within say_joe #{name}"
  " joe #{name}"
end

a = %w(birds bees)

starting = "some"

b = a.reduce(starting) do  |total, x|
  puts x
  say_joe(x)
end

puts "-----"

puts "starting: #{starting}"
puts "a: #{a}"
puts "b: #{b}"
```

with output:

```
birds
within say_joe birds
bees
within say_joe bees
-----
starting: some
a: ["birds", "bees"]
b:  joe bees
```

What is the magic of reduce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The accumulation (in this case a string concatenation) doesn’t happen automatically. You still need to return the new accumulator value (remember in Ruby the last statement is also implicitly the return value).

This does what you’d expect:

```
def say_joe(name)
  puts "within say_joe #{name}"
  " joe #{name}"
end

a = %w(birds bees)

starting = "some"

b = a.reduce(starting) do  |total, x|
  puts x

  total << say_joe(x)
end

puts "-----"

puts "starting: #{starting}"
puts "a: #{a}"
puts "b: #{b}” # some joe birds joe bees
```

Comment: For this reason, I tend to prefer `each_with_object` with complex accumulators (hashes/arrays). Does the same thing and does not require to return new value of memo. :)

Comment: thanks - so total -> b and is then accessible outside the block. So I know my example sucks - is there a killer use case for using `reduce`?  It seems like it gets mentioned as some supertool but I just don't really get it. I feel like most of the example are easily achieved with `each` or its variations.  I asked the question so certainly not asking you to justify it - more curious about what (if anything) I'm missing.

Comment: @timpone "is there a killer use case for using reduce" - "reduce" is also known as "fold" (in some other languages). So, if you want to collapse/compress a collection into a single value, that's where you don't use `each`, you use `reduce`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - thx, and looking at your other comment re `each_with_object`, it seems like reduce basically removes the need to have a tmp variable (or perhaps puts it inline). I just felt like I was missing some big concept but am not feeling that way anymore.

Comment: @timpone: The big thing about `inject` / `reduce` / `fold` / *catamorphisms* is that it is a *general method of iteration*. In other words: *everything* that can be done with a `for` loop can also be done with `reduce` *but without requiring side-effects*. A loop *does not work* without side-effects, whereas `reduce` *never* needs side-effects.

Comment: @timpone: `reduce` is about feeding the result of a calculation into itself. Given `f = ->(m,i) { m+i }`, then `[1,2,3].reduce(0, &f)` is `f[f[f[0,1],2],3]`. `reduce` isn't really about accumulation (IMO that's `each_with_object`'s job), it is more about feedback and recursion.